# How to increase the zoom ratio when do pinch to zoom in graph - AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

We are using AChargEngine in our android application and it is working perfectly fine.
But when I do pinch to zoom it's zooming very less, I want to increase that zoom ratio.

Example:

If I do normal pinch to zoom and in that case if it is zooming 100px then I want it to zoom 200px doing normal pinch to zoom.

Is there any way I can achieve this thing?

Help is required.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**

Here is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blutdruck_chart_landscape);
    loadChart();
    mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(BlutDruckChartLandscape.this,
             mDataset,
             mRenderer);
}

public void loadChart() {
    initChart();
    setRenderingStyle();
    fillData(WEEK);

    if (graphDatas.size() > 0) {
        mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { (dateLabels[0].longValue() - (GraphUtilities.DAY)), mRenderer.getXAxisMax(), mRenderer.getYAxisMin(), mRenderer.getYAxisMax() });
    }
}

public void initChart() {
    mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    mDiastolicSeries = new TimeSeries("Diastolic");
    mSystolicSeries = new TimeSeries("Systolic");
    mPulseSeries = new TimeSeries("Pulse");
    mDataset.addSeries(mDiastolicSeries);
    mDataset.addSeries(mSystolicSeries);
    if (isPulseEnabled) {
        mDataset.addSeries(mPulseSeries);
    }
    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mDiastolicRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mDiastolicRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    mDiastolicRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    mDiastolicRenderer.setLineWidth(GraphUtilities.LINE_WIDHT * multiplicationFactor);
    mDiastolicRenderer.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graph_diastolic_gray));
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mDiastolicRenderer);

    mSystolicRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mSystolicRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    mSystolicRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    mSystolicRenderer.setLineWidth(GraphUtilities.LINE_WIDHT * multiplicationFactor);
    mSystolicRenderer.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graph_systolic_blue));
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mSystolicRenderer);

    mPulseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mPulseRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    mPulseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    mPulseRenderer.setLineWidth(GraphUtilities.LINE_WIDHT * multiplicationFactor);
    mPulseRenderer.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graph_pulse_white));
    if (isPulseEnabled) {
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mPulseRenderer);
    }
}

public void setRenderingStyle() {
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ilink_blue));
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ilink_blue));
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGridX(false);
    mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGridY(true);
    mRenderer.setAntialiasing(true); // Also tried setting antialiasing to false but not helped.
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(-30.0f);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(GraphUtilities.POINT_SIZE * multiplicationFactor);
    mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(GraphUtilities.TEXT_SIZE * multiplicationFactor);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(GraphUtilities.TEXT_SIZE * multiplicationFactor);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(GraphUtilities.TEXT_SIZE * multiplicationFactor);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { (int) (5 * multiplicationFactor), (int) (25 * multiplicationFactor), (int) (10 * multiplicationFactor), (int) (10 * multiplicationFactor) });
    mRenderer.setShowTickMarks(false);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsVerticalPadding(-2 * multiplicationFactor);
    mRenderer.setZoomRate(5.0f);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you :

```
            multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
            multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(enabled);
            multiRenderer.setZoomInLimitX("VALUE");
            multiRenderer.setZoomInLimitY("VALUE");
```

OR

```
     multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
     multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(enabled);
     multiRenderer.setZoomLimits("Array of Zoom value of X and Y ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to do pinch zoom and the zoom ratio will increase as the velocity of pinch zoom increase.

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
{

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
}
```

Create a global double scaleFactor variable and use that value like following to apply scaling factor to your view.

```
    scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
```

Comment: Are you using it with AChartEngine? If yes can you please tell me complete code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify the source code. You can call `renderer.setZoomRate()` before building the graph itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here, we just provided the sample updated source code which helped us to achieve what was required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here, we just provided the sample updated source code (Changes in the setZoomRate() function) which helped us to achieve what was requires. We are not modifying the source code but need your inputs what we can do or change to achieve our required zooming. For the better understanding, we can also upload a video. we also used your suggestion by calling the function as mRenderer.setZoomRate(5.0f); Above provided source code sample shows the same. Please help us in this regard as it is urgent for us and we are in a bit time pressure. Thanks in Advanced !!

Comment: The pinch zoom feature was first written by me and then improved by other developers. If it is still not perfect, you have the source code and the chance to modify it to work the way you need it. I don't have time to keep modifying features whenever a user of the library doesn't like a certain feature.